# What does “there” refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> No matter where people are making new homes and offices, saving energy
>   is important. For us humans, the goal can be difficult. But for some of
>   our feathered friends, being energy efficient comes naturally. Just
>   take a look up ***there***.

What does "there " refer to?

Comment: The place where the birds are.  :)

Answer (score 3):

It talks about birds, our feathered friends.

> Just take a look up there (toward the sky, trees) - and you find them!